# How can I include JavaFx 2.0 in an Eclipse RAP application

Tags: javafx

is it possible to use JavaFX 2.0 in an RAP (not RCP) application?

regards

Answer (score 0):

RAP (Rich Ajax Platform) uses Javascript on the client side, while JavaFX runs native Java on the client side (either in an applet, Java WebStart application, or locally deployed application). While you may be able to embed a Java applet using JavaFX into a RAP application, they are fundamentally different technologies. You may be better off exploring integrating some client-side Javascript toolkits that provide similar functionality.